# nextAuth nextjs and expressjs

Tags: next-auth

I am trying to send my credentials from NEXTJS to express API with AXIOS in next-auth when I try doing it I always get an error but when I use the fetch API it works perfectly [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM9Qb.png)

I am trying to send credentials to my external API with AXIOS but I always get and error but when I use the fetch API it works perfectly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).